# Understanding NonFatal implementation in Scala

Tags: scala, exception, pattern-matching

I'm now looking at the NonFatal extractor implementation and have a question about it actually:

```
object NonFatal {
   def apply(t: Throwable): Boolean = t match {
     case _: VirtualMachineError | _: ThreadDeath | _: InterruptedException | _: LinkageError | _: ControlThrowable => false
     case _ => true
   }

  def unapply(t: Throwable): Option[Throwable] = if (apply(t)) Some(t) else None
}
```

Is that a common pattern to handle exception in Scala? Say, I have `IllegalArgumentException`, `ExecutionException` and `InterruptedException` being wrapped in `IOException` (API requires to do so). In case of `IllegalArgumentException` and `ExecutionException.getCause == IllegalArgumentException` it means some data are corrupted. So I'm currently tend to do the following:

```
object CorruptedData {
  def apply(t: Throwable): Boolean = t match {
    case t: IllegalArgumentException =>
      true
    case t: ExecutionException if t.getCause.isInstanceOf[IllegalArgumentException] =>
      true
    case _ => false

  }

  def unapply(t: Throwable): Option[Throwable] = Some(t).filter(apply)
}
```

Is it common to do things like that? Same as with standard library.

Comment: Not _too_ common, and not really exception-specific, but perfectly normal.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Thanks for your comment. Got it.